# How can $x^n-\lfloor x\rfloor \ge x(x-1)(n-1)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm watching [this problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2i4CuOloD0s&t=229s&ab_channel=MichaelPenn) on YouTube, and I'm trying to follow. Here's the problem:

Find all $x\in \Bbb R \ge0$ and $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $x^n-\lfloor x\rfloor = n$.

Eventually, he started covering all values of $x$ and $n$ within the set $(1,\infty)$.

I haven't watched the entire video, but the part I'm on now, **I believe** he's doing something to determine the minimum values for $x$ and $n$ (within this set). To do so, he's creating *if* statements that create the minimum values.

First such *if* statement is this:

$$x=\lfloor x \rfloor$$

That would mean that:

$$\begin{align}x^n-\lfloor x \rfloor &=\lfloor x \rfloor^n -\lfloor x \rfloor    \\
& =\lfloor x \rfloor(\lfloor x \rfloor^{n-1}-1)\\ 
& = \lfloor x \rfloor(\lfloor x \rfloor-1)(\lfloor x \rfloor^{n-2}+\lfloor x \rfloor^{n-3}...+\lfloor x \rfloor+1) \\
& = \lfloor x \rfloor(\lfloor x \rfloor-1)\sum^n_{k=2}\lfloor x \rfloor^{n-k}
\end{align}$$

Second *if* statement is this:
$$\lfloor x \rfloor =1$$

That would mean that:

$$\lfloor x \rfloor(\lfloor x \rfloor-1)\sum^n_{k=2}\lfloor x \rfloor^{n-k}=\lfloor x \rfloor(\lfloor x \rfloor-1)(n-1)$$

Which he uses to determine that for the set $(1,\infty)$, this is true: $x^n-\lfloor x\rfloor \ge \lfloor x \rfloor(\lfloor x \rfloor-1)(n-1)$.

But the second *if* statement also means that $x = 1$ since $\lfloor x \rfloor =1$ and $x =\lfloor x \rfloor =1$. This second *if* statement violates the premise of this part of the explanation, because it makes it so that $x\notin(1,\infty)$

So, how can $x^n-\lfloor x\rfloor \ge \lfloor x \rfloor(\lfloor x \rfloor-1)(n-1)$ be true when the set chosen from is $(1,\infty)$?

**EDIT:**

*This edit has been altered*. I'm not sure my confusion came out clearly. At 5:43 in the video, Penn finds this:

$$n\ge x(x-1)(n-1)$$

However, to arrive at this lowest possible value for $n$, given the set of $(1,\infty)$, he first had to:

1. Allow $x=\lfloor x \rfloor$
2. Allow $\lfloor x \rfloor = 1$

However, this becomes a violation of the set, since $x$ cannot be $1$.

So, given this, how can $n$ be equal to that equation without the parameters being broken? Surely, the conclusion is rather:

$$n\gt x(x-1)(n-1)$$

Comment: Have you tried [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality)?

Comment: Could you please tell me the time stamp where he says ”if $x=[x]$” and ”if $[x]=1$”? I am asking because at 3.50 he has written $x = [x] + \{x\} \geq [x]$ and $[x]\geq 1$ which are statements quite different from what you have written.

Comment: @AndréArmatowski He doesn't say exactly that, so there is no time stamp. But by writing $\ge$, he opens up for the possibility of $x=\lfloor x \rfloor$, which is obviously possible. Later, he opens up for the possibility of $\lfloor x \rfloor = 1$. With his last factorization, he opens up for the possibility that $n$ is equal to $x(x-1)(n-1)$. However, if $n$ is to be equal to $x(x-1)(n-1)$, then these two criteria must be met: $x=\lfloor x \rfloor$ and $\lfloor x \rfloor = 1$. In my understanding, these two criteria cannot coexist.

Comment: Sure it is a possibility but not a necessity. “$a\geq b$” is defined as $a>b$ or $a=b$ where “or” signifies that either the first is true, the second is true or both. Therefor e we can write $1\geq 0$, because $1>0$, and not because $1$ might equal $0$

Comment: @AndréArmatowski I didn't know that, I thought it had to mean that both were true. However, is still don't see how $n=x(x-1)(n-1)$ can be seen as a possibility given that two mutually exclusive criteria must be met for this equality to be possible.

Comment: @AndréArmatowski No, because if $\lfloor x \rfloor = 2$, then $\sum_{k=2}^n\lfloor x \rfloor^{n-k} \neq n-1$. It is only when $\lfloor x \rfloor =1$ that the aforementioned sum is equal to $n-1$, and simultaneously, $n$ is only equal to $x(x-1)\sum_{k=2}^n\lfloor x \rfloor^{n-k}$ when $x=\lfloor x \rfloor$. For $n$ to be equal to $x(x-1)(n-1)$, two criteria must be met: $x=\lfloor x \rfloor$ and $\lfloor x \rfloor = 1$, and when it is necessitated that $x \in (1,\infty)$, those two criteria cannot be met at the same time. Thus, there should be a strict inequality, not a $\ge$.

Comment: So you are claiming to me that $2\ne 2(2-1)(2-1)$?

Comment: @AndréArmatowski No, I am saying that $2(2-1)(2-1)$ does not follow from $x^n-\lfloor x \rfloor$, because for one to arrive to that spot, $x^n-\lfloor x \rfloor$ must be factorized to $x(x-1)(n-1)$, which requires both $x=\lfloor x \rfloor$ and $\lfloor x \rfloor = 1$ (two criteria who are mutually exclusive).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127047/discussion-between-andre-armatowski-and-a-kvale).

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere does Michael Penn suggest that $\lfloor x\rfloor =x$.
What he rather does is to consider $x>1$ and estimate $x^n-\lfloor x\rfloor $ from below. If we write $x=k+\theta$ with $k\in\Bbb N$ and $\theta\in[0,1)$ (to get rid of the floor and fractional part function symbols), then $x\ge k\ge 1$ implies $x^n\ge k^n$ and so
$$\tag1n = x^n-k\ge k^n-k=k(k-1)(\underbrace{k^{n-2}+k^{n-3}+\cdots + k +1}_{\ge n-1})\ge k(k-1)(n-1)$$

Let's distinghuish three cases: $n=1$, $n=2$, $n\ge 3$

- Checking the original equation for $n=1$ explicitly, we arrive at the condition
  $$ (k+\theta)^1-k=1,$$
  i.e., $\theta=1$, which is absurd.
- If $n=2$, then $(1)$ gives us $k(k-1)\le 2$, i.e. $k\in\{1,2\}$. So either
  $$ (1+\theta)^2-1=2\qquad\text{or}\qquad (2+\theta)^2-2=2,$$or expanded,
  $$ 2\theta+\theta^2-2=0\qquad\text{or}\qquad 4\theta+\theta^2=0.$$
  These quadratic equations have solutions
  $$\theta=-1\pm\sqrt 3\qquad\text{or}\qquad \theta\in\{0,-\tfrac14\}.$$
  As we need $0\le\theta<1$, the only valid solutions are $k=1$, $\theta=\sqrt 3-1$, i.e., $x=\sqrt 3$ and $k=2$, $\theta=0$, so $x=2$.
  Indeed,
  $$\sqrt3^2-\lfloor \sqrt 3\rfloor =3-1=2\qquad\text{and}\qquad2^2-\lfloor 2\rfloor =4-2=2,$$
  giving us two solutions.
- If $n\ge 3$, then $(1)$, divided by $n-1$, gives us
  $$ k(k-1)\le \frac n{n-1}=1+\frac1{n-1}\le 1+\frac 12<2$$
  so we must have $k=1$. Then our equation becomes $(1+\theta)^n-1=n$, from which we obtain $\theta=\sqrt[n]{n+1}-1$ and ultimately
  $$ x=\sqrt[n]{n+1}$$
  (for which indeed $\lfloor x\rfloor =1$, as desired).

Answer (score 0):

[From](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Notation)
$$x=\lfloor x \rfloor + \{x\}, \{x\}\in[0,1)$$
we have
$$x^n - \lfloor x \rfloor=
x^n-x+\{x\}\geq x^n-x=x(x^{n-1}-1)\tag{1}$$
Using [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) and given $x\geq 1 \Rightarrow x-1\geq0$
$$x^{n-1}=(x-1+1)^{n-1}\geq (x-1)(n-1)+1\Rightarrow\\
x^{n-1}-1\geq (x-1)(n-1) \tag{2}$$
Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$
$$x^n - \lfloor x \rfloor\geq x(x-1)(n-1)$$
for $x\geq 1$.

Comment: "(...) and given $x \ge 1$ (...)". This is my issue. The set of $(1,\infty)$ means that $x \gt 1$, not $\ge$. Given that this calculation was first based on the event where $x$ and the floor of $x$ are equal, it is necessary that the rest of the calculation follow the rules $x$, which were defined as belonging to $(1,\infty)$. The whole $(n-1)$ was a part of a factorization that required $x = \lfloor x \rfloor$, but to arrive at the $(n-1)$, $\lfloor x \rfloor$ needed to be equal to $1$, which through the previous and necessary *if* statement is impossible.

Comment: @A.Kvåle, well, because the statement is true for $x\geq1$, it is true for $x>1$. My point is, using Bernoulli's inequality it's a lot easier to prove it.